# What is the correct notation for “has opposite sign than”?

Tags: notation

What symbol should replace the question mark in the expression below
$$a\text{ ? }b$$
in order to express that $a$ and $b$ have opposite signs, i.e.:

$$a<0 \text{ when } b>0$$
$$a>0 \text{ when } b<0$$

Comment: You could use $a b < 0$ for example.

Comment: I suggest you post this as an answer, because I'm starting to think that there is no such symbol, in which case this would be the correct answer!

Comment: In case $ab$ doesn’t make sense, try $a=\lambda b$ where $\lambda<0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use $a b < 0$ for example. Or $a b \leq 0$ if $a$ or $b$ can be zero.

Comment: or even $\frac{a}{b}<0$, we like fancy stuff.